# iptables Multicast Traffic Dropped on WAN

Tags: linux, networking, router, iptables, multicast

For my home router, I am running a small Debian box which connects to my ISP via a separate modem using PPPoE.

I have had some iptables rules in place for quite a while which:

- Allow all traffic on local interfaces
- Provide NAT for local devices behind the router (e.g. forwarding, allowing related INPUT traffic on the WAN etc.)
- Open ports on the WAN for a VPN on the router
- Allow IGMP echo requests for remote monitoring
- Port forward WAN 80/443 for a web server behind the router

After this, all other traffic is Dropped (on the WAN).

I decided to look into logging the dropped traffic as I was curious as to what iptables is dropping (or whom is trying to attack my network, ha).

In the logs, I noticed multicast traffic was getting dropped.

For example:

```
Feb 16 18:19:34 router kernel: [1234949.398845] iptables drop: IN=ppp0 OUT= MAC= SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=36 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=22057 DF PROTO=2
```

As you can see, it is on the WAN (ppp0), and this doesn't point to being from any external IP in particular (0.0.0.0).

My rules allow for related traffic to be allow back into the WAN via the INPUT chain, so what I'm asking are the following questions:

- What would cause multicast traffic on the WAN like this (or appear to be multicast traffic entering the WAN)?
- Should I continue blocking this traffic, or should I allow it? Is it a risk if I did allow it? Am I missing out on something useful/helpful by continuing to block it?

Comment: Does your ISP also provide TV (even if not to you)?

Comment: @EugenRieck Yes, I believe my ISP does offer IPTV as an option. I don't subscribe to this service, but ADSL/VDSL multicast is available on my line. Do you think this could be IPTV broadcast related?

Comment: Many ISPs that support IPTV use multicast for "announcements", i.e. channel lists, server endpoints etc. These go to ALL users on the network, not only subscribers. I learned this the hard way when being on the other side.

Comment: @EugenRieck Makes sense I guess. I'm just wondering that if I did want to subscribe to IPTV, would my current rules be blocking the required packets? I don't want to just allow this traffic and somehow open myself up to an exploit.

Comment: If you were to subscibe to IPTV, you'd get a settop box that connects directly to the WAN side. It will have a private (10.x.y.z) IP completely unmanaged by you. So your router settings have no relevance for IPTV (Caveat: if your ISP's system works like many others do, but the multicast makes me thinks so)

Comment: multicast output can be looped back to itself and seen in the INPUT rules (and be mostly harmless). I don't know if this can be the case for your setup, but the easiest to know is to mark it in output (iptables -I OUTPUT ... -j MARK), if it's the same packet looped back, the mark will be present in INPUT and will be in the logged line. conntrack doesn't track multicast correctly (it's just not really possible). marks can help